# Pyspark - passing list/tuple to toDF function

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, and want to rename it using toDF by passing the columns names from list, here column list is dynamic, when i do as below getting error, how can i achieve this?

```
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dept: string (nullable = true)

columns = ['NAME_FIRST', 'DEPT_NAME']

df2 = df.toDF('ID', 'NAME_FIRST', 'DEPT_NAME')
(or) 
df2 = df.toDF('id', columns[0], columns[1])
```

this, does not work if we dont know how many columns would be there in the input data frame, so want to pass the list to df2, i tried as below

```
df2 = df.toDF('id', columns)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.\nOld column names (3): id, name, dept\nNew column names (2): id, name_first, dept_name"
```

Here it treats list as single item, how to pass the columns from list?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

df2 = df.toDF(columns) does not work, add a * like below -

```
columns = ['NAME_FIRST', 'DEPT_NAME']

df2 = df.toDF(*columns)
```

> "*" is the "splat" operator: It takes a list as input, and expands it into actual positional arguments in the function call

Comment: If only I could give more than just one thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

What you tried is correct except you did not add all columns to your "columns" array.

This will work:

```
columns = ['ID','NAME_FIRST', 'DEPT_NAME']
df2 = df.toDF(columns)
```

Updating answer with all steps I followed in pyspark:

```
list=[(1,'a','b'),(2,'c','d'),(3,'e','f')]
df = sc.parallelize(list)
columns = ['ID','NAME_FIRST', 'DEPT_NAME']
df2 = df.toDF(columns)
```

Comment: what you are doing here is creating a new dataframe but question is how to rename existing dataframe by passing a list. Once you execute your above code, try executing `newCols = ['emp_id','FIRST_name', 'DEPT_NAME']` and `df.toDF(newCols)` and see if that works

Comment: I agree with you. I missed the part that OP was trying to rename columns.